# Script to Change File Dates from Folder Name

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I need help and hoping this is the place for it.  Or if you can recommend where I should ask for this help, I would appreciate it.

Obstacle:  I have many files that I need the date changed to the name of the folder they exist within.  I would like a script that would cycle through each folder and do this automatically.   Let me know what can be done and am open to suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] a good question. Then please provide a [mcve] of the code you are attempting to use.  We are more than happy to help you troubleshoot problems you are having with your code. We are not here to write an entire script for you.

Comment: Regardless, just so we are clear on the technical specifications of your request, are you wanting to change the system modified date of the files to the name of the folder then they exist in?  If so, that cannot be done with a native batch file without third party tools.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your scenario correctly, this should do what you need:

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Directory
foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $folder.Name -Force | Where-Object {! $_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object {$_.CreationTime=($folder.Name)}
}
```

Depending on what date you want to set you can change the property of either: CreationTime, LastAccessTime or LastWriteTime

Comment: Mike - thanks.  Is there syntax to where I could place this at the top level of a set of folder to let it go through each folder and update the files?  I would like to avoid having to go to each folder and run the script.  I used to be capable in DOS but am lost here.  Thanks.

Comment: @JCombs are you saying you want parse an entire folder tree instead of just one folder deep like the existing script is doing? You could start by reading the help for the `get-childitem` and you would see the option `-recurse` which is essentially the same as your good old "DOS" command `dir /ad /s`.

Comment: @JCombs You can save Mike's script in a .ps1 file and drop the .ps1 on the parent folder where all those child folders with dates are and it should work perfectly fine you could change `$folders = Get-ChildItem -Directory` for `$folders = Get-ChildItem $psscriptroot -Directory` but by default `Get-ChildItem` should take the script directory as input.

Comment: @JCombs You will want to run the script at the top level, where all the folders with names "YYYY-MM-DD" are located. It will set the datetime on all the files inside each folder to the date indicated in the name of the folder.

Comment: @Mike I tried running it in PowerShell but nothing happens.  Is there a way to echo what is happening to see?  I could share my folders if that would help.

Answer (score 0):

One solution :

```
function Convert-DateString ([String]$Date, [String[]]$Format)
{
   $result = New-Object DateTime
 
   $convertible = [DateTime]::TryParseExact(
      $Date,
      $Format,
      [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,
      [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None,
      [ref]$result)
 
   if ($convertible) { $result }
}

#take all dir with correct format
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\tmp2" -directory | where Name -like "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]" | %{

$CurrentDir=$_

#try to convert name directoy to date
$NewDate=Convert-DateString -Date $CurrentDir.Name -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"

#if date is correct
if($NewDate)
{
    #modify all creation date file with new date
    Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -file | %{$_.CreationTime=$NewDate}
} 

}
```